# How to isolate devices on WLAN from LAN but give them access to only one device on LAN?

Tags: routing

I have a system that has a network where customers' devices are connected wirelessly and they fetch some data from a Pc connected to the network by a cable. 
I would like to isolate customers from the local area network (LAN) but give them access to that Pc only to get data. Is that possible? Can I do that on a guest network?

**Edit**

I have no access to the network. I have a system for shopping malls that serves their customers and I want to have access to their database to get some data. I am a beginner in networking. what I am thinking of is connecting additional access point to the existing network and build wireless guest network with access to specific PC on the local network. On that PC, there is a software installed to receive connections from customers then go to database, get data, and send it back to customers
([Ron Trunk](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2142/ron-trunk) I can not comment! Please have a look at the edit)

**Edit2**

I am not trying to hack a network. The shopping mall has its own private local network and its owners want to buy my system.
Here is more information about the system: the user enters the mall with his mobile device then he connects to open wifi network. on this network there is also a PC where a software is installed. The user's smartphone ask that software to give it some data by connecting to it through the network.
My problem is the software does not have the data, the data stored on the mall's database and to connect to database the PC should be connected to the mall's private network. 
Now I have that pc in the middle between users and database. So I am thinking to connect the PC to the private LAN and connect addition AP to the LAN. On the AP, I will build guest network where users will be isolated from the LAN. Now they are isolated but I want them to access the PC which is connected to the LAN. Is there a way to do that?
[Ron Maupin♦](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8499/ron-maupin)

Comment: It all depends on the kind of equipment you have.  Please include the models of your network equipment and perhaps a simple diagram of your network.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks over which you have no control are explicitly off-topic here. If the network owners want you to have access to their data, they will grant you access to their data. Bypassing network security or policies is also explicitly off-topic here, and hacking a network to gain access to data is illegal.

Comment: Without information about the network and the equipment models, we can't give you an answer.  It's not about hacking the network - you're asking us to tell you how to set up a network without knowing anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this using ***Access-List*** or any Firewall feature that makes possible it.

I make that on Mikrotik using the FW feature (**Filter Rules**), for instance.

```
LAN 1 - 192.168.0.0/24
LAN 2 - 192.168.10.0/24
WLAN  - 192.168.100.0/24
```

Both LAN 1 and 2 can access any wireless device, like a PRINTER, but any wireless device can establish a communication in LANs. I had to create a exception, just one wireless device (NOTEBOOK) could access my FTP Server.

```
 1   ;;; FTP ACCESS
     chain=forward action=accept src-address=192.168.100.53 
     dst-address=192.168.0.96 

 2   ;;; DENY TCP WIRELESS COMMUNICATION
     chain=forward action=drop protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.100.0/24 
     dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 

 3   ;;; DENY ICMP WIRELESS COMMUNICATION
     chain=forward action=drop protocol=icmp src-address=192.168.100.0/24 
     dst-address=192.168.0.0/24
```

Like Ron said, depends on kind of equipment you have.